# using iphone camera to detect and recognise numbers

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to make iPhone camera detect numbers and convert it to valid numbers which I can use in app calculation?

I did see this open source project "Tesseract-iPhone-Demo-master" but it did not work properly. Any hints can help me with this idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tesseract Library will only give you t the text present on the image. This library is not that much of accurate as you say . Tesseract will give you the best result for high dpi images like above 150 dpis. After that all the validation  for the number should done by your self like:
NSString *originalString = @"This is my string. #1234";

```
NSString *numberString;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];
int number = [numberString integerValue];
```